# Firebase Rules - How to check if user exists in sub document

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on a Forum-like structure using Firebase Store / Firebase Rules. My structure is something like this:

```
Collection --- Document ------ Collection --- Document
Topic1         CreationDate    UsersJoined    UserUID1
Topic2         Title                          UserUID2
Topic3         UpdatedDate                    UserUID3
...            ...                            ...
```

Basically, each Topic has a Collection of Users. My goal is to be able to write a security rule where only Users in the 'UsersJoined' can read/write to the corresponding Topic. This is what I have right now as my rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Topics/{topicUID} { 
      allow read, create, update, delete: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Topics/$(topicUID)/UsersJoined/$(request.auth.uid));

      match /UsersJoined/{userUID=**} {
        allow read, create, update, delete;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when I use the built in Simulator, the read works just fine; however, when I request to read it via my code for IOS, it tells me that I don't have sufficient permission.

I've tried just doing `allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;`, and I am able to read. I am confident that the UserUID does exist within the UsersJoined collection.

I've also tried creating a "sister" collection where I store my User IDs in, so my structure looks like this:

```
Collection ----------- Document
MyTestUserCollection   UserUID1
Topic1                 UserUID2 
Topic2                 ...
...
```

I then used this rule: `if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/MyTestUserCollection/$(request.auth.uid));` and the read works as well, both on the simulator and IOS codes.

My problem is not being able to read when the User List is nested within the Topic. So my question is... by writing a rule that checks ("reads") data in a nested collection, am I violating the "allow read" rule (since technically it hasn't determined whether I can read yet)? Or am I over complicating things a bit and there is a better way to structure my Collections/Documents? Or am I just not writing the rule correctly?

I don't believe my code on IOS is the issue, but just in case this is what I'm doing to request to read from my database: (the user is logged in via Firebase Auth)

```
[[myFirestore collectionWithPath:@"Topics"]
 getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
     if (error != nil) {
         NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Read it");
     }
 }];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security rules allow a user to read a specific topic, if they are following that topic. Your code tries to read all topics, which your rules don't allow. So that explains why the server rejects the read operation.

This is easiest to remember by realizing that rules themselves don't filter data. They instead either allow a listener or not. And since your rules don't allow a listener on all of `/Topics`, that listener gets rejected.

One solution is to only read the specific topic that you are a follower of. To determine the topic(s), you might need to store a document with the user's list of topics, such as in a `/Profiles` collection. This is quite common on NoSQL databases: you're essentially storing both sides of the many-to-many relationship.

Alternatively you can try to [validate the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query), but I'm not quite sure if that can be made to work for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I totally get. I thought the rule would check per Topic, versus the rule checking for the entire /Topics. I guess I was treating the rule as a filter in a way, which is bad. I'll probably end up creating a separate user profile as suggested to keep a list of Topics they are following. Although... the link you provided interest me as well as I feel that is a step closer to what I want. I think where I would run into a problem in that solution would be writing the "where" clause on the IOS side, but that's something for me to play around with =) Thanks again Frank!